# Can multiple Slack users connect to a Salesforce Org using a single Salesforce user?

Tags: apex, slack, slack-salesforce-app

Is there a way to synchronize multiple Slack users with a Salesforce Org using a single Salesforce user, considering that I have integrated Slack and Salesforce using Salesforce For Slack Apps or Ape SDK for Slack? The objective is to have multiple Slack user connect to the Salesforce Org within single Salesforce user, while the remaining logic and processes will be based on individual user Accounts.

[image]